# Twitter bootstrap tokenfield cancel .on('beforeCreateToken')

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tokenfield

Twitter bootstrap tokenfield

Is there a way to cancel the creation of a token inside .on('beforeCreateToken') if invalid input is detected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I assume you are using this library -> http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/ ??

Just reset the token in the `beforeCreateToken` handler, here if the token about to be inserted is contained in a exclusion list  :

```js
var exclusionList = ['a','b','c'];

$('#tokenfield').on('beforeCreateToken', function(e) {
  var token = e.token.value;
  if (exclusionList.indexOf(token)>-1) {
    e.token=false;
  } 
});
```

If empty, the token is not being inserted (rather obvoius :)

---

From the source, about line 176-178 in latest development version v0.11.0 (https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield/blob/master/js/bootstrap-tokenfield.js) :

```
  this.$element.trigger( beforeCreateEvent )

  if (!beforeCreateEvent.token) return
```

beforeCreateToken is triggered inside `createToken()`, if you set `e.token` to false or empty, the function is exited and

```
var token = $('<div class="token" />')
            .attr('data-value', value)
            .append('<span class="token-label" />')
            .append('<a href="#" class="close" tabindex="-1">&times;</a>')
```

is never reached. So this is actually *thé* way to cancel the creation.

Comment: Thanks! That way a empty token is created. I want to abort the Creation.

Comment: No. Nothing is created when it is empty. Alternatively, set e.token to false (as I have updated the answer) - using the latest downloadable version. Check the code for yourself, if you set the token to false (or empty) the creation is cancelled by return.